# Closed abelian subgroup of $\operatorname{SU}(n)$

Tags: lie-groups, compactness, abelian-groups

I'm confused why every closed abelian subgroup of $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ is contained in a maximal torus. I think there must be an obvious way to see this since the conclusion is so strong, but I failed to see how at the moment. Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be such a group.

By the spectral theorem, any matrix of $SU(n)$ is diagonalisable in an orthonormal basis.

Since $G$ is a abelian, elements of $G$ commute with each other and are therefore simultaneously diagonalisable.

But that means that it exists $P\in SU(n)$ (this is where the "in an orthonormal basis" part comes in) such that $PGP^{-1} \subset T$ where $T$ is the standard torus of diagonal matrix.

This shows that any such $G$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $T$. The result follows immediately : just take $P^{-1}TP$ which is maximal because $T$ is.

Comment: Ah, clever argument! Thanks!